# Fenwick tree Sum query

Tags: string, binary, logic, binary-indexed-tree

This is the code for the sum query from Index 0 to Index X

```
Int query(int x){ 
Int sum=0;
for(; x>0; x -= x &(-x) )
   sum += BIT[x]; 
 Return sum; 
 }
```

I have two arrays `BIT[] and a[]`.  I store the values from array a to BIT for queries. Now according to the loop, what we do is add value at index X and then change the index by removing the last set bit from it.

For eg if I call query(14) it will execute as follows :

> Sum= BIT[14] + BIT[12]+ BIT[8]

It will stop after Index 8 as 8 is `1000` and after removing the last bit it becomes 0 and loop ends. So that means for index 14 I.e `1110` I access the array 3 times , I.e is the number of set bits. But I checked for long bits, it failed for eg `1000110111011101100`set bits are 11 but the answer is 12 . ***So is there other way to tell how many times I access the array during the execution of sum query by seeing the binary value of a index I*** ?

I can't figure it out. I tried many cases , for some it is less by 1 , for some it is more by 1 and for some it is actually the answer.

Please help me out.

Comment: Don't forget to tag the language. In C for example, `x &(-x)` will depend on the complement scheme of the signed type.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't require this code. All I want is to know the number of times I access BIT [] array for a given binary value of Index X.

Answer (score 1):

Number of accesses is exactly number of ones in binary representation. Here is the short Python (Python just because I am lazy) script that would print something if it would not be the case any number smaller than 1000000

```
def count(x):
  ones = 0
  for ch in bin(x): 
    if ch =='1':
      ones = ones + 1
  return ones

access = 0;
for y in range(1000000):
  access = 0
  x = y
  while x > 0:
    x = x -(x & (-x))
    access = access + 1
  if count(y) != access:
    print "Wrong:"+str(y)
```

Comment: I can't tell right now what is the right answer but there is specific condition for counting number of 1.

Comment: Maybe you think about updating the tree. For query it is number of "1". x&-x is the least significant bit. If you subtract it from x you get x with one less "1".